# How to add contextual information to log lines from multiprocessing workers?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a pool of worker processes (using `multiprocessing.Pool`) and want to log from these to a single log file. I am aware of logging servers, syslog, etc. but they all seem to require some changes to how my app is installed, monitored, logs processed etc. which I would like to avoid.

I am using CPython 2.6 on Linux.

Finally I stumbled into a [solution](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html) which almost works for me. The basic idea is that you start a log listener process, set up a queue between it and the worker processes, and the workers log into the queue (using `QueueHandler`), and the listener then formats and serializes the log lines to a file.

This is all working so far according to the solution linked above.

But then I wanted to have the workers log some contextual information, for example a job token, for every log line. In `pool.apply_async()` method I can pass in the contextual info I want to be logged. Note that I am only interested in the contextual information while the worker is doing the specific job; when it is idle there should not be any contextual information if the worker wants to log something. So basically the log listener has log format specified as something like:

```
"%(job_token)s %(process)d %(asctime)s %(msg)"
```

and the workers are supposed to provide `job_token` as contextual info in the log record (the other format specifiers are standard).

I have looked at [custom log filters](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information). With custom filter I can create a filter when the job starts and apply the filter to the root logger, but I am using 3rd party modules which create their own loggers (typically at module import time), and my custom filter is not applied to them.

Is there a way to make this work in the above setup? Or is there some alternative way to make this work (remember that I would still prefer a single log file, no separate log servers, job-specific contextual information for worker log lines)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters can be applied to handlers as well as loggers - so you can just apply the filter to your QueueHandler. If this handler is attached to the root logger in your processes, then any logging by third party modules should also be handled by the handler, so you should get the context in those logged events, too.

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different, so I haven't actually verified if it would work. However, based on my understanding of the logging module it seems like it should work, so awarding the answer.